# vba - Look up in Loop

Tags: vba, foreach, vlookup

i try to do a vLookup for each cell, but it doesn't seem to work

```
Sub Extern()

    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim j As Range
    Dim e As Range

    lRow = Worksheets("Übersicht").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    c = 41

    For Each j In Worksheets("Übersicht").Range("A41:A" & lRow)

        Set Rng = Worksheets("Übersicht").Range("B" & c)

        For I = 3 To WS_Count
            If Worksheets(I).Name Like "*uslastu*" Then

                Rng.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(j,Worksheets(I)!B:C,2)"

            End If
        Next I

        c = c + 1
    Next j
End Sub
```

Please help, if you notice any errors.When I try to debug it, it says the Lookup formular, is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause you put the variables j and I inside the mark "" , therefore VBA understand it is the text, and doesnt pass any value into these variables. As the result, your formula will be error.

You can try this for your formula:

```
"=VLOOKUP(" & j.Address & "," & Worksheets(I).Name & "!B:C,2,0)"
```